# How to detect value change event for built-in 'select' editor in Tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

I am using the built-in 'select' editor in Tabulator. How can I detect value change event, to process the data that the user selected in dropdown?

```
{
    field: 'gender',
    title: 'Gender',
    headerFilter: 'input',
    editor: "select",
    editorParams: {"male": "Male", "female": "Female"}
},
```

Comment: On the Tabulator website, find the Callbacks section. Then look for the cellEdited callback. That should do what you want. (Sorry, on mobile so I can’t get the links easily.)

Comment: I read that page like 5 times but somehow missed that section. Please post this as an answer if you need the points... Thanks!